# make rowspan in header text along with columnspan implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make first two headings with `rowspan` 2. `Columnspan` of 2 is already implemented. How can I make these two headers rowspan of 2? Please see the attached image.

```
protected void StdGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StdGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].RowSpan = 2; // not getting desired result
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.Text = "";
    cell.ColumnSpan = 2;

    row.Controls.Add(cell);
    cell = new TableHeaderCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = 7;
    cell.Text = "MANAGEMENT";
    cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
}
```

The first two columns "SN" and "SYM NUM" have columnspan of 2, how can I implement `rowspan` in these two headers?
[image]